# Text in the tablerow overflows when it is long and breaks the whole order

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, text-size

If the text in the tablerow is long, it breaks all cells, I want it to remain fixed or the text to shift

```
 <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginVertical="30dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
        android:background="#f1f1f1"
        >

        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="fospfdmglfdmglğpkdsağgorjgdfglkdfdsfsdfsdfg"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"/>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLyRy.png)

Comment: Edit your question and add to it your xml code.

Comment: I added now, I added now I don't want the cell to be distorted when the text is long, I want it to shift or I want it to shrink according to the cells.

Comment: You should possibly use `maxWidth` or `maxLength` on your `TextView` to limit the space it can occupy.